# Resetting a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Is there any way to reset a for loop while reading a dictionary ? I am trying to add items to the dictionary in the for loop while reading it so those items are not being traversed.

For Example:

```
def assignCircuits( jugglerPriority, numberofJugglerPerCircuit, numberofCircuit):
    circuitAssign = defaultdict(list)

for juggler,jugglerChoice in jugglerPriority():
    for choice in jugglerChoice:
        circuit, productVal = choice
        if len(circuitAssign[circuit]) < numberofJugglerPerCircuit:
            circuitAssign[circuit].append(dict(jugglerName = juggler, jugglerParams = jugglerChoice,value=productVal))
            from operator import itemgetter
            circuitAssign[circuit] = sorted(circuitAssign[circuit], key=itemgetter('value')) 
            break;
        elif productVal > circuitAssign[circuit][0]['value'] and len(circuitAssign[circuit]) == numberofJugglerPerCircuit:
            jugglerRemoved = circuitAssign[circuit].pop(0)
            print jugglerRemoved
            print productVal
            print circuitAssign[circuit][-1]['value']
            circuitAssign[circuit].append(dict(jugglerName = juggler, jugglerParams = jugglerChoice, value=productVal))
            from operator import itemgetter
            circuitAssign[circuit] = sorted(circuitAssign[circuit], key=itemgetter('value')) 
            jugglerPriority[jugglerRemoved['jugglerName']].append(jugglerRemoved['jugglerParams'])
            break
        else:
            continue

return circuitAssign
```

Since I am reading and modifying the dictionary at the same time I want to reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always dangerous changing a collection that you are iterating through.

Previously I have used an index and traversed the collection from the end towards the start - any additions of deletions will not affect the items I have not managed yet. Not sure best way to do in Python.